# bisection method, Numerical Analysis

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider the method of bisection applied to $f(x) = \arctan(x)$, with initial interval $x = [-4.9, 5.1].$

Are the hypotheses under which the method of bisection converges valid?  If so, then how many iterations would it take to obtain the solution to within an absolute error of $10^{-2}$?

Please help!!

Comment: Well, what are the hypotheses for the method of bisection? Where are you having trouble checking them?

Comment: What is the width of the initial interval?  How many times would you have to divide that by two to get $\leq 10^{-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

As a first working answer, I am getting 8 iterations are required.

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -4.9 & 0.1 & 5.1 \\
 1 & -4.9 & -2.4 & 0.1 \\
 2 & -2.4 & -1.15 & 0.1 \\
 3 & -1.15 & -0.525 & 0.1 \\
 4 & -0.525 & -0.2125 & 0.1 \\
 5 & -0.2125 & -0.05625 & 0.1 \\
 6 & -0.05625 & 0.021875 & 0.1 \\
 7 & -0.05625 & -0.0171875 & 0.021875 \\
 8 & -0.0171875 & 0.00234375 & 0.021875 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The middle number is the estimate of the root. Notice the sign change in the first and last columns. That is how interval bisection zeroes in on a root. Generally it takes about 3 iterations to get 1 correct digit. It is quite robust but quite slow.